# ant says "< was unexpected at this time"

Tags: java, android, windows, ant, path

I downloaded ant from mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.bz2
and installed it on Windows 7 as described here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#windows

but on entering *ant -version* into the console, if get this error message: 
*< was unexpected at this time.*

Please follow this link to see a screenshot of the command prompt:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVJmbAKs1tYeWhiTjNjNUdLSVk/view?usp=sharing

If ant was properly installed, the output should be something like *Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4*

Please point out the problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you check the hash checksum of the download to verify the integrity of the tar.bz2 file?  Make sure you do not have another 'ant' in your search path.  If all that looks good, you can edit ant.bat directly to disable `@echo off` so you can see how far the script goes before you see the error.

Comment: Thanks a ton @ewh! I followed your suggestion to disable `@echo off` in ant.bat and found out the cause of error. The problem turned out to be in java's classpath and not the windows path. There was an extra double quote in one of the classpath arguments.